# Getting the Range Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a following table resulting from a query

[image]

I want to get the best range list that fits the above 269 range using the MaxmiumDays Column. Please check the following Output.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: Please don't post images of data, provide it as `text`.

Comment: @TheImpaler if I check the less than to the Maxmium Days I will get all 3 records. But according to the logic it should be in the 365 Maxium Days Record. Like it is Greater than 30 days but less than 365 ..

Comment: Do you mean that for a specific number of 'Days' you want to return the lowest `MaximumDays` value, or rather the row with the lowest `MaximumDays`?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information on what you have and what your want. We don't know the system you're working with and we don't have specifics to help.

Comment: @Spider So, you want TWO rows? Totally unclear to me. Downvoting.

Comment: What is the basic problem that you need to solve? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @TheImpaler - Yeah. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For older version you can use `outer apply` :

```
select t.*
from table t outer apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table t1
      where t1.id < t.id
      order by t1.id desc
     ) t1
where (t.days > t1.maximumdays or t1.maximumdays is null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `lag()` might be the simplest method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(maximumdays, 1, 0) over (order by id) as prev_maximumdays
      from t
     ) t
where days >= prev_maximumdays;
```

In SQL Server 2008, you have several options.  Assuming you can trust the `id`, the best is:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.prev.id = t.id - 1
where days >= t.prev.maximumdays;
```

Comment: My Apologies. Sql server version is 2008 R2

Comment: I think 1st query works perfectly in SQL server 2014, But I doubt the 2nd query..

Answer (score 1):

It appears he wants for a given number of days in this case 269- he wants the rows with closest values of MaximumDays surrounding that- in this case 30 and 365. is that correct?

UPDATE:

Not sure if you need the entire records or just the Days and Range..this is one way to do it..

```
declare @tab table 
(id int, Rate int, days int, maximumdays int)
insert into @tab
select 1,30, 269,30
UNION
select 2,35, 269,9999
UNION
select 3,40, 269,365
UNION
select 4,45, 369,330
UNION
select 5,50, 469,365

;With DayRange as(
select distinct 
    Days, 
    (select max( t2.MaximumDays) from @tab t2 where t2.MaximumDays < t1.Days and t1.Days=t2.Days
    ) as Range_Start, 
    (select min(t3.MaximumDays) from @tab t3 where t3.MaximumDays > t1.Days and t1.Days=t3.Days
    ) as Range_End 
from @tab t1)
select t1.*
from DayRange DR 
inner join @tab t1 on DR.Days=t1.Days and (DR.Range_start=t1.MaximumDays OR DR.Range_End =t1.maximumdays)
```

Comment: thanks pointing that out. Please notice that these type of comments are best placed under comments, not posted as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I need 50 reputation to post as comment

Comment: Ok, then I hereby give you 10.  :)